# C++ elapsed time = 0

Tags: c++, profiling, c++-chrono

I have a code written in C++ in Visual Studio:

```
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    result = function(-1, 1, 9999999);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    double time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
    time_taken *= 1e-6;
    std::cout << "result: " << result << "time : " << fixed << time_taken << setprecision(6) << " sec" << endl;
```

The problem is: I run the code in Release mode and `time_taken` always equals 0. When I switch to the Debug mode `time_taken` is between 1 and 2 seconds. I tried different ways to pinpoint time but `time_taken` always equals 0. How can I fix this? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: That sounds like a well optimized function to me. Does `function` require any runtime input or it can be calculated entirely during compilation?

Comment: If the compiler can prove that the function has no visible effects, it'll throw the function out at higher optimization levels. If it finds that it can compute a constant result at compile time and serve that constant at runtime, it will. See the [As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)

Comment: Side note: It is helpful to think of your code not as a list of instructions for the computer, but instead as a description of program behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are lacking clock resolution. Or the function was partly or fully optimized away.

Generally it is not trivial to profile small functions.

One thing you should do is to call it a lot of times, and measure time of whole run, then divide this time by number of calls.

Also make sure the function is actually fully computed at runtime by stroing result in a volatile variable, and taking input from volatile variables.

Comment: using a profiler is trivial, writing a profiler from scratch is not ;)

Comment: for tiny function that is called infrequently, or even _just once_ even using a profiler is not trivial, unfortunately. There's no efficient ways to profile them. The good thing is that one doesn't need to profile them, as they don't consume much time :)

Comment: exactly, taking no measurable time is a good enough profiling result

Comment: The function I call is not trivial. It has a volatile variable. When I run the code with 10^9 operations the displayed time equals 0, and with 10^10 - about 30 seconds